# Why does my puppy like to bite her foot?

Tags: dogs, behavior

Sometimes my puppy will bite her foot. I can't tell if she is bored or playing, but the bite looks fairly aggressive which is odd to me since it's herself she is biting. She does like to nibble on toys and furniture (which we do not let her on the furniture), so I'm trying to understand if this is normal behavior. She is fairly hyper a lot of the time.

[Here is a video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByNi02RoHJUIelVKdHFyZzJtVjg/view?usp=drivesdk) of her chewing her foot (I'd upload it, but imgur doesn't like it).

Comment: Equivalent to a baby sucking its thumb?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I agree with both answers but have you considered this:

You mentioned she's very hyper and you think she could be bored. That is a strong possibility to consider. Pit bulls are very intelligent and you need to make sure they are challenged mentally as well as physically. Training is a must and will help bound even more.
But they also need to be told that being quiet and resting is most important, otherwise you could get further problems.

Good article here:

http://dogtime.com/dog-health/general/1544-dog-training-settle-down-dunbar

And btw: Puppies chew. That's how they "test" the world, with their mouth

Comment: Oh I know about the chewing part - believe me! ;)

Answer (score 4):

Sometimes puppies like to play with their feet and will bite at them or paw at the inside of their mouths.

Gnawing/licking excessively at paws on the other hand can indicate allergies or something irritating the paws (like ice or salt). Looks like you have a pitbull, I STRONGLY suggest getting pet insurance as they are VERY prone to allergies as they get older - allergies will be really hard on the wallet. I would even go as far as putting him on a diet made for allergies and will benefit skin and coat. Veterinary dermatologists like to use the [Iams K/O diet](http://www.iams.com/dog-food/veterinary-formula-dog-food-skin-coat-health-ko) and the main source of protein is kangaroo which isn't a common allergen.

Good luck! :)

Comment: I wouldn't say that it is excessive.  Her paws look very clean, and as far as I know, the dirt and grass outside doesn't have anything abnormal in it to irritate them (neither does my house flooring).

Comment: What you showed in the video looks like play, with allergies you will see that the paws will look red/brown. Red from inflammation and the brown tinge from saliva.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest checking it for any lumps or anything different that would make her want to scratch it. But if she is all good, it may be that she just likes messing around with her leg because if it hurt her she would stop doing it or yelp.